# R replace list elements from within a function

Tags: r, function

In R I'd like to replace some elements in a list using the `$` notation:

```
# functions
replaceNonNull <- function(x, value) {
  if(!is.null(x)){
    thisx <- deparse(substitute(x))
    
    print(paste0("replacing ", thisx, " with  '",value,"'"))
    
    #x <<- value
    assign(thisx, value, envir = .GlobalEnv)
  }
}
mylist = list("a"=1:3)
replaceNonNull(mylist$a,"456");mylist$a
```

However after running replaceNonNull, a **new** variable is created with name `'mylist$a'`. How can I change the `a` value in the list instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you're having is that the first argument of `assign` is:

> x - a variable name, given as a character string.

But even outside the function, this doesn't work.

```
assign(mylist$a,0)
#Error in assign(mylist$a, 0) : invalid first argument
assign("mylist$a",0)
mylist
#$a
#[1] 1 2 3
```

However, you *can* use `$<-`, like this:

```
> mylist$a <- 0
> mylist$a
[1] 0
```

One approach, then is to create that expression and evaluate it:

```
mylist = list("a"=1:3)
myexpression <- deparse(substitute(mylist$a))
myexpression
#[1] "mylist$a"

library(rlang)
expr(!!parse_expr(myexpression) <- 0)
#mylist$a <- 0
eval(expr(!!parse_expr(myexpression) <- 0))
mylist$a
#[1] 0
```

Obviously use `<<-` inside the function.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you want something like this:

```r
replaceNonNull <- function(x, el, value, env = globalenv()) {
  if (!is.null(x[[el]])) {
    nx <- deparse(substitute(x))
    nv <- deparse(substitute(value))
    cat("replacing value of", sQuote(el), "in", sQuote(nx), "with", sQuote(nv), "\n")
    env[[nx]][[el]] <- value
  }
}

mylist <- list(a = 1:3)
replaceNonNull(mylist, "a", 4:6)
## replacing value of ‘a’ in ‘mylist’ with ‘4:6’
mylist$a
## [1] 4 5 6
replaceNonNull(mylist, "b", 4:6)
mylist$b
## NULL
```

Nonstandard evaluation is a dangerous game, so you should be aware of the limitations. Here, `x` *must* be the name of a variable bound in `env` (hence *not* a call to the `$` operator). Otherwise, you will continue to see unexpected behaviour:

```r
mylist <- list(zzz = list(a = 1:3))
replaceNonNull(mylist$zzz, "a", 4:6)
## replacing value of ‘a’ in ‘mylist$zzz’ with ‘4:6’
mylist$zzz$a
## [1] 1 2 3
`mylist$zzz`
## $a
## [1] 4 5 6
```

You can avoid unintended assignments by adding a test:

```r
replaceNonNull <- function(x, el, value, env = globalenv()) {
  nx <- deparse(substitute(x))
  if (!exists(nx, env, mode = "list")) {
    stop("There is no list in ", sQuote("env"), " named ", sQuote(nx), ".")
  }
  if (!is.null(x[[el]])) {
    nv <- deparse(substitute(value))
    cat("replacing value of", sQuote(el), "in", sQuote(nx), "with", sQuote(nv), "\n")
    env[[nx]][[el]] <- value
  }
}

rm(`mylist$zzz`) # clean up after last example
replaceNonNull(mylist$zzz, "a", 4:6)
## Error in replaceNonNull(mylist$zzz, "a", 4:6) : 
##   There is no list in ‘env’ named ‘mylist$zzz’.
```

Comment: I know, that is why I'm asking the question. Any idea why the `$` notation isn't working as expected though?

Comment: @gaut Because `assign` doesn't evaluate expressions. It assigns values to names, and the name you are giving is `mylist$zzz`.